# Start a little business of hemp beer

Tags: beer

My father started a small cultivation of hemp (~ 2 ha) for business. I would like to start to make my beer from hemp. Unfortunately i am an absolute beginner on this subject.

- Which are the most delicate steps?
- Are there some references of this kind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only beer I know of that uses hemp is Uinta Dubhe (pronounced 'doobie'). In this episode of [Can You Brew It](http://thebrewingnetwork.com/shows/844), the brewer talks about how he uses it and how it can be pretty tricky to deal with. I believe he says that it turns to a peanut-butter-like mush in the mash tun.

He does not malt the hemp, but he may roast it. It's been a while since I listened to the episode and I don't remember.

Comment: Cool Beer also makes a Hemp beer: http://www.coolbeer.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=12&Itemid=3 It looks like they don't malt the hemp either, but add it after.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the Hemp kernels would have to be malted? I'm really not sure. I'm guessing you would still use a base malt for the majority of your mash (2 row pale barley) and use the hemp as a specialty malt. I do remember a Hemp beer from Greece I has several years ago in Ajax. It was really nice, a unique flavour. Keep digging. Someone has tried this before I gaurentee! Good luck.